# unix bash - save environment variable and loop

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

Let's say you have a first.sh file in a directory: "/home/userbob/scripts/foo/". Basically I would like to know how to loop through specific directories, each time going back up to a higher level directory and repeating.

The .sh file has something like this pseudocode:

```
#!/bin/bash
curdi={$PATH} #where the first.sh file sits on the server
FOLDERS="$curdi/waffles/inner/
$curdi/pancakes/inner/
$curdi/bagels/inner/"
for f in $FOLDERS
do
    cd $f
     cp innerofinner/* .
     cd $curdi
done
```

The idea is to somehow copy all the contents of /home/userbob/scripts/foo/waffles/inner/innerofinner to /home/userbob/scripts/foo/waffles/inner/
(and basically repeating just with the path having pancakes, bagels.etc.)

Can't do it for all directories (*) under /home/userbob/scripts/foo/ because there are some that I don't want to copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
for name in waffles pancakes bagels
do
    cp "$curdi/$name/inner/innferofinner/"* "$curdi/waffles/inner"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Walking file trees? Sounds like a job for `find`!

```
#!/usr/local/bin/env bash

# only environment variables should be all-caps
dirs=({bagels,pancakes}/inner)

find "${dirs[@]}" -type d -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -name innerofinner -execdir bash -c 'cp "$1"/* .' -- {}  \;
```

I did a partial path and assumed a working directory of `/home/userbob/scripts/foo`. An absolute path would work, too, and would look like

```
dirs=(/home/userbob/scripts/foo/{bagels,pancakes}/inner)
```

This finds all directories exactly one level below the listed directory that are named "innerofinner" and, in their parent directories, executs bash and a simple `cp` script.

If you're wondering how this works, read below.

The `dirs=()` syntax creates an empty array named `dirs`. `dirs+(a b)` creates an array with `a` at index 0 and `b` at index 1. Any whitespace-delimited string will work, here. In a shell script `{a,b,c}` expands to `a b c` but `A{a,b,c}B` expands to `AaB AbB AcB`. So specifying `{bagels,pancakes}/inner` is just a way to say both `bagels/inner` and `pancakes/inner` without having to type as much.

A variable in bash can be expanded with `$foo` or with `${foo}`; these are the same. An array in shell can be expanded to all of its elements with `${foo[@]}` delimited by spaces (if you know perl or php this will make some sense) and quoting the expansion (always a good idea in shell!) prevents spaces innside the variable from being processed again by the shell. Thus, `"${dir[@]}"` becomes `bagels/inner pancakes/inner`.

Knowing this we see that the find command has become `find bagels/inner pancakes/inner -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -name innerofinner` and if you execute this it will return exactly two lines: both full paths to each `innerofinner` directory. All we want now is to do something for each one, which `-execdir` does nicely.

Comment: When executed with bash first.sh I get the following error:        find: bad option -maxdepth
find: [-H | -L] path-list predicate-list

Comment: @toop: What version of `find` do you have? You may have to specify `-maxdepth` and `-mindepth` immediately following the directories (that is, move `-type d` to just before `-execudir`)

Answer (score 0):

Use a recursive function or invoke the script recursively.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your problem statement correctly. Your psuedo code seems good. But, I see a problem with the following line.

```
curdi={$PWD}
```

It does not give you the directory where the script resides but gives the directory you are in. If your script directory is in the path and you are running the script from your home directory then $curdi would point to your home directory and not the directory where your script resides. This will lead to undesired results.

Answer (score 0):

```
find . \( -iname '*waffles*innferofinner*' -o \
          -iname '*pancakes*innferofinner*' -o \
          -iname '*baggels*innferofinner*' \) \
          -type f \
          -exec cp {} "`echo {} | sed 's:\(.*\)/[^/]\+/[^/]\+:\1:'` \;
```

Should do. Finds every file in the desired subdirs, then copies it based on its name.

HTH

Comment: first.sh: -iname: not found
first.sh: -iname: not found
first.sh: -type: not found
first.sh: -exec: not found

Comment: Escaping `{}` this way is not necessary. Also, spaces will be a problem and you seem to be missing a trailing `\;`

Answer (score 0):

Incidentally, if you really wanted to do it in the way that your pseudo-script attempts it, you'd do it like this

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for f in "$PWD"/{waffles,pancakes,bagels}/inner ; do
    cd "$f"
    cp innerofinner/* .

    # if you know for sure that it's one level up
    cd ..
done
```

Presuming that `$PWD` is a good enough indicator of "current" directory for you. Me, I'd pass it in to the script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

base="${1-$PWD}"

for f in "$base"/{waffles,pancakes,bagels}/inner ; do
    cd "$f"
    cp innerofinner/* .
    cd ..
done
```

at call it like

```
breakfast.sh /home/userbob/scripts/foo/
```

Comment: The first part of the answer gives me: `do^M' unexpected at line 4

Comment: @toop: Your file has DOS-style line endings and needs to be converted. Use `dos2unix` if you have it and in the future don't write your scripts in notepad (or upload them with FTP in text mode).